# Can I use a different function which is less volatile than INDRIECT()

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, time, excel-formula, volatile

I'm currently using the INDIRECT() function to search a list of names in a list which relate to tab names in google sheets and then show a specific cell related to this.

The tab names can change monthly hence why I have been using INDIRECT() but I now know this to be volatile and not always recalculate automatically

The formula I'm using is below where AK17 is the top of the list which goes down to AK32 and in this instance BN17 is the cell I wish to show if this tab is present in AK17.

=iferror(INDIRECT(""&AK17&"!BN17"),"0")

Is there an alternative, less volatile process I can follow?

If you need more info I'd be happy to provide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in GS `INDIRECT` is not volatile as in Excel. anyway, you can use:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(AK17&"!BN17"), IFERROR(NOW()/0)*1&"")
```

to force it to recalculate every minute with:

[image]

Comment: simplicity at it's finest! Thank you so much works like a charm.